# Loop through subdirs and (1) copy files to another dir (2) renaming them to their md5 hash

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

Consider the following directory structure:

```
rootdir
  subdir_1
     12345.tif
     56789.tif
  subdir_2
     00000.tif
  ...
  subdir_n
     99999.tif
     54321.tif
     54345.tif
```

I need to:

1. loop through this structure
2. calculate the md5 for each tif file
3. copy [md5.tif] to another folder (disregarding the folderstructure).

So the desired output would be:

```
newdir
   2070e4cfb8f24209647d3c9ec55098ee.tif
   52e31fe630cebe73cc959d371bd6b353.tif
   eec032f144f5af1be2b7f0535a2010d2.tif
   936ed95431293660e3499d88e5ae22b0.tif
   8bc884dce30d89b53b120adb8bd658b2.tif
   ec87470ae6683b539ea69004894e23dd.tif
```

I now have (in PS 2.0 bc that's what I have to work with):

```
Get-ChildItem "D:\rootdir" -filter *.tif |
  Foreach-Object {
    $content = Get-Content $_.FullName
    $md5     = New-Object -TypeName  

    System.Security.Cryptography.MD5CryptoServiceProvider
    $hash = [System.BitConverter]::ToString($md5.ComputeHash([System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes($content)))

    ## Write-Host $hash = CB-A9-EB-00-92-18-06-71-D9-DD-7C-2A-08-D9-D9-EF

    Set-Content $_.FullName('newroot/'+ $hash +'.tif')
}
```

The first problem here is that the MD5 has `-` in between. So what am I doing wrong here?

Second, Why is the new file not written to the filesystem?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, those dashes are the result of `[System.BitConverter]::ToString()`. You can remove them if you want. And second, if you're copying a file, you should call `Copy-Item` instead of `Set-Content`. Like this:

```
$md5 = New-Object -TypeName System.Security.Cryptography.MD5CryptoServiceProvider
Get-ChildItem "D:\rootdir" -filter *.tif -Recurse |
Foreach-Object {
    $hash = [System.BitConverter]::ToString($md5.ComputeHash([System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes($_.fullname)))
    $hash = $hash -replace "-","" # drop all dashes off $hash

    Copy-Item -Path $_.fullname -Destination "newroot/$hash.tif"
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This would seem to be working. However, when I run it (I set executionpolicy to unrestricted), nothing is happening. No error message. The folders exist. I'm running PS elevated. Any thoughts? Also, if I put in for instance a `Write-Host $hash`, nothing appears in the console? Could it be that it does not iterate through the subfolders (there are no images in the rootfolder itself)? I tried `Get-ChildItem "D:\rootdir\*"` but it made no difference.

Comment: Yep, because there's a missing `-recurse` switch in `Get-ChildItem`, because it was missing in your code.

Comment: Thanks. I get the error `Exception calling "ReadAllBytes" with "1" argument(s): "Illegal characters in path."` Am I defining the path wrong? In reality, the path has spaces in it (`D:/My Data/FOO/BAR/BAZ 0001/`)

Comment: Hmm, I had to look at your code more thoroughly. See, `ReadAllBytes()` accepts a file name, while your code (and in turn my code) fed it the file's content. Fixed. Also I've moved `md5` out of the loop, we don't need more than a single MD5 hasher.